# Java Socket.readLine() not always reading whole message separated by newLine

Tags: java, sockets, readline

readLine() works fine in many cases but few times, the line I read in by BufferedReader.readLine() is incomplete line. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436609/bufferedreader-readline-before-the-line-is-complete) question talks about similar issue. However the solutions are not satisfactory. A solution there says that it maybe because of EOF character. But in my case I am not sending any EOF character at all. Below are my codes:

```
/*Sending Code*/
public void sendToLocalDaemon(String msg){/*msg have no New line or \r*/
        localMachineWriter.println(msg);
}
/*Receiving Code*/
public int receiveFromCoordinator(){
        String response = "";
        while(true){/*Each message separated from new line will have its independent meaning.*/
            try{
                    coordinator.setSoTimeout(1);
                    try{
                        response = coordinatorReader.readLine();
                    }
                    catch(java.net.SocketTimeoutException e){
                        response = null;
                    }
                    if(response == null){
                        return coordinatorsMessage.size();
                    }
                    coordinatorsMessage.add(response);
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                log(e.getMessage());
                //System.exit(0);
            }
    }
}
/*This is how I set reader and writer*/

public void setReaderWriter() throws IOException{
    this.coordinatorWriter = new PrintWriter(coordinator.getOutputStream(),true);
    this.coordinatorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(coordinator.getInputStream()));
}
```

Please either suggest me someway to make this work correctly. Or suggest me some other way by which I can read whole message, with 100% guarantee.

Comment: Could you add the input that causes the line read in by `BufferedReader.readLine()` to be an incomplete line, to your question? For instance - the whole input and what `readLine()` outputs.

Comment: As stated in one of the answers in your linked question, I think the process which writes to your socket has not ended writing to your socket when you read it.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I can paste the input, but I have examined its happening with any string. My messages are composed of (0-9 and : and # and _ and letter 'E' and letter 'A'). This problem is occurring with long strings only.

Comment: @Supahupe yes, that maybe true. But isn't readLine supposed to wait till it doesn't encounters newLine? And if not than, any idea how to force it to do that? One way is I can write a wrapper on my own, But I am wondering does java provides any existing solution for it?

Comment: I'm wondering if `BufferedReader's` default buffer size is large enough for your use case. From the documentation - *The buffer size may be specified, or the default size may be used. **The default is large enough for most purposes.***

Comment: @JonnyHenly I have tried by specifying buffer size(this.localMachine.setSendBufferSize(Constants.maxMessageSize +1);) for socket with both, using the default size and then setting, a fairly loose upper bound on maximum possible length of my message, as buffer size for the socket .

Comment: Maybe your strings are bigger than the default size? I had a similar issue with an android app some time ago and decided to use a simple message class which is sent by converting it to json. We defined a max size for one message so i checked each string for its size and used two message-classes if a string was too big...

Comment: @Supahupe What is the default size for Sockets and buffered reader? My max size is not more than 35KB. And I am setting send and receive buffer size for the Socket. I have tried with both default value and with maxMessageSize(a liberal upper bound). Not for the buffered reader.

Comment: There is no EOF character. It isn't clear what you mean by 'supposed to wait until it doesn't encounter new line'.

Comment: @EJP I mean readLine() should not return till it doesn't reads a newLine character

Comment: That's meaningless. You mean until it *does* read a newline character. Surely.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your read timeout. If it happens, you can lose data. If `readLine()` times out in the middle of a line, the part read so far is lost. If you set it too short, you will lose a lot of data, and you're setting it much too short. You should set it much higher, or not use one at all.

Comment: I think socket will timeout, if it doesn't receive anything set time. This is what doc says "Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds. With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this amount of time. If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout."

Comment: I am trying to say that if the readLine is reading(and not blocking ideally) than on timeout it should not be interrupt. Or it is interrupted exactly at timeout no matter what action is being done on socket?

Comment: If it isn't blocked it won't timeout, just like the documentation says. The timeout only happens if it has blocked for the entire timeout period. If it receives half a line and then blocks for the entire timeout period waiting for the other half and the line terminator, it will throw `SocketTimeoutEzception` and lose the half line received. I am wondering what exactly you are using the timeout for, as you don't appear to understand what it does. What problem are you trying to solve with it?

Comment: I don't want to block on the socket reading. So I was using timeout. Was not using NIO as there anyways it may read partial messages. What I want to do is to communicate between a bunch of clients and a server which mutually sends distinct messages(separated by new line). I want complete message to reach to my application, at both end, in one go. So I was using readLine.

Comment: Well you *are* blocking, for up to one second *per character*, and also *another* second *per line*, for the line terminator. And experience is showing that one second is too short. So your strategy isn't working. If you don't want to grapple with NIO, and I'm not saying you should, you should use a thread per socket, dedicated to reading it.